# Does this modular congruence have a solution?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Prove that every number in $\mathbb{Z}$ is a solution to the congruence 
>   $$x^7 − 2x \equiv x \ \ (\operatorname{mod} 42)$$

As far as I can see, this congruence does not have any solutions (for example if we take $x=3$, the output is incorrect), but the book says I need to prove otherwise. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The claim to be proved is indeed false; it is even easier to see that for $x=1$ it fails.

Comment: the statement is not true. e.g $1^7 - 2(1) - 1 = -2$ is not divisible by $42$

Comment: what book are you reading?

Comment: In the future, please use [mathjax to format your questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It seems daunting at first, but you’ll pick it up quickly :)

Comment: The correct congruence is $x^7 \equiv x \pmod{42}$. So $x^7 - 2x \equiv x \pmod{42} \iff x \equiv 0 \pmod{21}$.

Comment: The statement is definitely not true.

Comment: @DanielFischer can you explain how you came to to 0 and 21? For science reasons :)
Thanks to everyone else for the feedback! Appreciate it

Comment: Using $x^7 \equiv x \pmod{42}$ we get $x^7 - 2x \equiv x - 2x \equiv -x \pmod{42}$. And hence $$x^7 - 2x \equiv x \pmod{42} \iff -x \equiv x \pmod{42} \iff 2x \equiv 0 \pmod{42}\,.$$ Now, $42 \mid 2x \iff 21 \mid x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the given congruence has solutions, and you are right,  $x=3$ is not one of them.

In order to find them, since $42=2\cdot 3\cdot 7$, it follows  that the congruence is equivalent to the system
$$\begin{cases}
x^7 − 3x \equiv 0 &\pmod{2}\\
x^7 − 3x \equiv 0 &\pmod{3}\\
x^7 − 3x \equiv 0 &\pmod{7}
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x-x \equiv 0 &\pmod{2}\\
x -0\equiv 0 &\pmod{3}\\
x-3x \equiv 0 &\pmod{7}
\end{cases}$$
because, by the [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $x^p\equiv x \pmod{p}$ for any prime $p$.
Can you take it from here?